# import a just-installed package into an existing python session

Tags: python, import, easy-install

Is it possible to make a python session aware of new libraries which have been `easy_install`ed since the session was launched?

I have a console which has run for a few days, and finally came up with the (large) result. I realized upon inspecting the results that I would require another package (`nltk`) for processing, which I installed, but the session can't `import` it (new ones can). The problem is, I can't seem to save the unprocessed results (`pickle` and `marshal` give me errors about string lengths) and I really don't want to re-run the week-long procedure.

Comment: Can you write the data to a file, without pickle/marshal? What kind of data are you dealing with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231011/how-to-easy-install-egg-plugin-and-load-it-without-restarting-application

Comment: They are tweets (as provided by `tweetstream`) -- highly nested structures, dictionaries in lists etc, so not straightforward to save.

Comment: Have you tried using pickle with a different protocol than teh default? (pass pickle.dump the number "-1" for protocol)

Comment: @zigg : although it is not a duplicate of the question you point to (the other question is a bit more complex), the answer works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try loading the new package using the [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module:

```
from imp import *
file, pathname, description = find_module('nltk')
nltk = load_module('nltk', file, pathname, ('.py', 'U', 1))
```

You may need to specify a path argument for find_module if python can't find the newly installed module:

```
file, pathname, description = find_module('nltk', '/path/to/nltk')
```

Replacing the last argument with the path that nltk was installed to.