# how to import a python module before installing it?

Tags: python, unix

So I'm trying to create a `setup.py` file do deploy a test framework in python.
The library has dependencies in `pexpect` and `easy_install`. So, after installing `easy_install`, I need to install `s3cmd` which is a tool to work with Amazon's S3.
However, to configure `s3cmd` I use `pexpect`, but if you want to run `setup.py` from a fresh VM, so we run into an `ImportError`:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import pexpect # pexpect is not installed ... it will be

def install_s3cmd():
    subprocess.call(['sudo easy_install s3cmd'])
    # now use pexpect to configure s3cdm
    child = pexpect.spawn('s3cmd --configure')
    child.expect ('(?i)Access Key')
    # ... more code down there

def main():
    subprocess.call(['sudo apt-get install python-setuptools']) # installs easy_install
    subprocess.call(['sudo easy_install pexpect']) # installs pexpect
    install_s3cmd()
    # ... more code down here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I know of course I could create a another file, `initial_setup.py` to have `easy_install` and `pexpect` installed, before using `setup.py`, but my question is: Is there a way to `import pexpect` before having it installed? The library will be installed before using it, but does the Python interpreter will accept the `import pexpect` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't accept it like that, but Python allows you to import things everywhere, not only in the global scope. So you can postpone the import until the time when you really need it:

```
def install_s3cmd():
    subprocess.call(['easy_install', 's3cmd'])

    # assuming that by now it's already been installed
    import pexpect

    # now use pexpect to configure s3cdm
    child = pexpect.spawn('s3cmd --configure')
    child.expect ('(?i)Access Key')
    # ... more code down there
```

EDIT: there is a peculiarity with using setuptools this way, since the .pth file will not be reloaded until Python relaunches. You can enforce reloading though (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249176/770830)):

```
import subprocess, pkg_resources
subprocess.call(['easy_install', 'pexpect'])
pkg_resources.get_distribution('pexpect').activate()
import pexpect  # Now works
```

(Unrelated: I'd rather assume that the script itself is called with the needed privileges, not use `sudo` in it. That will be useful with virtualenv.)

Comment: The first time there's an error ( I think python didn't find out the module has been installed). The second time it works. How could I avoid that?

Comment: I got the following error: `global name 'pkg_distribution' is not defined`

Comment: @philippe, sorry, my bad. That should be `pkg_resources`. You need to import that as well. Updated.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'distribution'` are you sure? :-(

Comment: Capital `D` in distribution

Comment: @philippe or `get_distribution`. Sorry, still before coffee.

Comment: the script was failing before ...  i will try with pkg_resources.get_distribution('pexpect') to se the results